# MySQL 5.1 exit code documentation?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

Can someone point me at the docs for the termination codes for MySQL 5.1?

I have a MySQL 5.1.41 installation on an Ubuntu server that seems to be crashing about every 90 seconds with the following message in syslog:

> init: mysql main precess terminated with status 2
>
> init: mysql main process ended, respawning

Googling for MySQL and  "termination code", "termination status", "exit code", or "exit status" yields nothing useful.   Apparently MySQL docs call this something different than what init is reporting.

Anyone have a guess?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the

```
/var/log/mysql.err
```

file for more information on why it's crashing.  Replace machinename with the hostname of your computer.

UPDATE:  I changed the .err file path. It should be correct now. It's based on information [found here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-mysql-error-log/).  It seems to correspond with a file on my Ubuntu installation.  Although on my machine, the file is empty.

Comment: Kibbee,

Thanks for the hint, but /var/lib/mysql/ appears to contain directory names for each of the databases on this server, but there is not a directory with a .err suffix.  I'll keep looking for additional error logs since there are a lot of different ways to congigure a MySQL installation.

Comment: It's `/var/log/` not `/var/lib/`
If you can't find it look into `my.cnf` file for error log location.

Comment: Kibbee,  Thanks.  It's empty on my machine too.  I'm pretty sure the MySQL docs now recommend logging to syslog rather than dedicated MySQL log files.